# Stored Procedure - not able to display no data found message

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created a procedure, which will take the Mgr number as input for execution.
When ever data is there for input passed Mgr number we are getting data. But when we don't have data it is not displaying "no data found" message.

```
create or replace procedure sp1 (mg number)
as
cursor c1 is select * from emp1 where mgr = mg;
i emp1%rowtype;
begin
for i in c1
loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.ename||' '||i.sal);
end loop;
exception 
when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('no data found');
end;
/
```

Can anyone please tell me how to display "no data found" message when there is no data for input Mgr number.

Thanks,
Subash

Answer (score 1):

Cursor can't return `no_data_found`, pure `select` can.

Here's one workaround: declare a local *counter* variable and see whether it changed.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp1 (mg number) as
  2    cursor c1 is select * from emp where mgr = mg;
  3    i emp%rowtype;
  4    l_cnt number := 0;                                --> this
  5  begin
  6    for i in c1 loop
  7      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;                             --> this
  8      dbms_output.put_line(i.ename ||' '|| i.sal);
  9    end loop;
 10    if l_cnt = 0 then                                 --> this
 11       dbms_output.put_line('no data found');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec sp1(7698);
ALLEN 1600
WARD 1250
MARTIN 1250
TURNER 1500
JAMES 950

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec sp1(76982);
no data found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to do everything manually, then you have to declare cursor, cursor variable, open cursor, open loop, fetch, exit, close loop, close cursor:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp1 (mg number) as
  2    cursor c1 is select * from emp where mgr = mg;
  3    i emp%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    open c1;
  6    loop
  7      fetch c1 into i;
  8      exit when c1%notfound;
  9      dbms_output.put_line(i.ename ||' '|| i.sal);
 10    end loop;
 11    close c1;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec sp1(7698);
ALLEN 1600
WARD 1250
MARTIN 1250
TURNER 1500
JAMES 950

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

By far the simplest option is a cursor for loop as Oracle does mostly everything for you:

```
create or replace procedure sp1 (mg number) as
begin
  for c1 in (select * from emp where mgr = mg) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c1.ename ||' '|| c1.sal);
  end loop;
end;
/
exec sp1(7698);
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine now.
one more doubt .. when ever we are retrieving multiple rows from Procedure it is working with for loop only.
When i try to write the code like ..
loop
fetch c1 into i
dbms_output,put_line(i.ename||' '||i.sal);
exit when c1%notfound;
end loop;

This code is not working ..

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info about *manually* doing everything and suggestion to use cursor FOR loop. Have a look, please.